# How to calculate time period?

Tags: functions, date-and-time

I have the starting and ending dates and times. And I need to calculate the night time in this period (from 10 pm (22) to 6 am (6)).

Example: 

starting date and time is {2015, 1, 4, 3, 10}

ending date and time is {2015, 3, 4, 18, 10}

Total (this is the result of function)= 1090 min (18 h 10 min)

How can I do this?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: your example results are not correct (?) else I don't understand the question, i get more like 500h.

Comment: do you need to be accurate if there is a daylight savings offset in the range?

Comment: no, I don't. it doesn't matter.

Comment: starting date and time is {2015, 1, 4, 3, 10} = {year, day, month, hour, minutes}

Comment: That's why I get like 18h but you more 500h

I tried to use your code and it didn't work correct: didn't calculate nightfirstpart
And for example I will have the ending date and time like this {2015, 3, 4, 22, 10}. In this case I need to take in account 10 minutes after 22 (10 pm).

Comment: Night time where? Duration varies by latitude...

Comment: @V_kid Your date and time specification is not correct.  Should be {year, month, day, hour, minute}. That is the form that is expected by Mathematica date and time functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d1 = {2015, 4, 1, 3, 10};
d2 = {2015, 4, 3, 18, 10};
j[d_, s_, h_] := Join[DatePlus[d, s][[1 ;; 3]], {h, 00}]
abst = AbsoluteTime;
l1 = DateRange[j[d1, -2, 22], j[d2, 2, 22]];
l2 = DateRange[j[d1, -1, 6], j[d2, 3, 6]];
ints = Interval /@ Map[abst, Transpose@{l1, l2}, {2}];
iu = IntervalUnion@@(IntervalIntersection[Interval[abst/@{d1,d2}], #] & /@ ints);
res = DateList @@ ((Differences /@ (List @@ iu) // Total));
DateDifference[{1900, 1, 1}, res, "Minute"]
(* {1130, "Minute"} *)
```

Note that your arithmetic is wrong and you're interchanging the month and day places in your lists

Comment: You're absolutely right. My arithmetic is wrong. It should be 18 h 50 m.
Your code works correct! Thank you! Can you help me to get the answer just in minutes?

Comment: @V_kid There you've it

Answer (score 1):

Edit, fixing some errors to show this "works"

```
 tend = AbsoluteTime[{2015, 4, 3, 18, 10}];
 deltimed = (tend - AbsoluteTime[{2015, 4, 1, 3, 10}])/3600/24;
 {wholedays, fractionseconds} = 
     {Floor[#], FractionalPart[#] 24 3600 } & @ deltimed;
 isnight[t_?NumericQ] := Boole[0 <= # < 6 || # >= 22] &@DateList[t][[4]];
 nightfirstpartday = 
      NIntegrate[isnight[t], {t, tend - fractionseconds, tend}]/3600 // 
                Quiet;
 answer = wholedays 8 + nightfirstpartday
```

> 18.8332

```
 {Quantity[Floor[#], "Hours"], 
   Quantity[60 FractionalPart[#], "Seconds"]} & @ answer
```

> {Quantity[18, "Hours"], Quantity[49.9931, "Seconds"]}

slow and inelegant.. but it does work.

Note you can in principle get the result in one shot like this:

```
 NIntegrate[isnight[t],
      {t, AbsoluteTime[{2015, 4, 1, 3, 10}], 
         AbsoluteTime[{2015, 4, 3, 18, 10}]}]/3600 // Quiet
```

This will severely loose accuracy if the time span is more than a few days however.

Answer (score 1):

Night time of First day + (night time period times [[2;;-2]] days) + night time of Last day

```
nightTime[{startDateTime_?DateObjectQ, endDateTime_?DateObjectQ}, {nightStartTime_?TimeObjectQ, nightEndTime_?TimeObjectQ}] :=
(* night time of First day + night time period \[Times] [[2;;-2]] \days + night time of Last day *)
 Simplify[
  Max[TimeObject[startDateTime] - nightStartTime, nightEndTime - TimeObject[startDateTime], Quantity[0, "Seconds"]] + 
   Max[(QuantityMagnitude@Floor@UnitConvert[endDateTime - startDateTime, "Days"] - 2)*
    ((TimeObject[{23, 59, 59}] - nightStartTime) + (nightEndTime - TimeObject[{0, 0, 0}])), Quantity[0, "Seconds"]] +
   If[(startDateTime - TimeObject[startDateTime]) == (endDateTime - TimeObject[endDateTime]),
    Max[TimeObject[endDateTime] - nightStartTime, nightEndTime - TimeObject[endDateTime], Quantity[0, "Seconds"]],
    Quantity[0, "Seconds"]
  ]
 ]
```

Let

```
start = DateObject@{2015, 1, 4, 3, 10};
end = DateObject@{2015, 3, 4, 18, 10};
nightStart = TimeObject[{22, 00}];
nightEnd = TimeObject[{6, 00}];
```

Then

```
timePeriod = nightTime[{start, end}, {nightStart, nightEnd}];
UnitConvert[timePeriod, "Hours"]
(* Quantity[458.818, "Hours"] *)
```

Hope this helps.

***Updated to account for date range less than 3 days ***

Now `end = DateObject@{2015, 1, 4, 18, 10};` and `nightTime[{start, end}, {nightStart, nightEnd}]` will work.

Comment: There is an assumption in this function that the time span is at least 3 days long but it is very easy to modify this by not accepting a negative for the middle days and comparing the date only part of startDateTime and endDateTime.

Comment: You ought to fix this to show the result with the corrected time spec.

Comment: @george2079 Yup. Done.